# In terraform if I want to get the name of an IAM role what shall I use, var.name or var.id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I don't want the complete ARN of my IAM role. I just want the name of it.
Should I use: var.name or var.id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Both are identical, so you can use either. From the [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role):

> id - Name of the role.

> name - Name of the role